# Wouldn't you need the subjunctive in "How could we expect an international language to exist.."?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, subjonctif

When I asked this French person to translate "How could we expect an international language to exist" he translated it as

> "Comment attendons-nous d'une langue internationale pour être"

But wouldn't you need the subjunctive?

> "Comment attendons-nous d'une langue internationale soit"?

If not, why would you use "Pour" if it doesn't mean "in order to" or "for"?

Comment: I can't imagine a French speaking native ever saying such a sentence. Even [google translate can do better](https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/How%20could%20we%20expect%20an%20international%20language%20to%20exist), although of course it's not quite good French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The verb is [**s'attendre à**](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/s%27attendre%20%C3%A0) and not *attendre*.
   Construction with *s'attendre à* is :

"s'attendre à ce que* + verb in the subjunctive".

2. You are right, *pour* cannot be used here.
3. "Exist" is *exister*  in French. We can't use *être* in this case.
4. Your sentence expresses regret. French uses the infinitive of the verb (and not a conjugated verb) in interrogative sentences expressing surprise, regret etc. (that will often be the case after *comment* and *pourquoi*).

Your sentence could then be :

> Comment nous attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale existe ?

But it is not the only possibility as "nous" can be replaced by "se" since this "nous" is a general "nous".

> Comment s'attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale existe ?

Your original English sentence had the idea of possibility ("could"). If you want to retain it in French you have to use *pouvoir*. If using *pouvoir* "s'attendre" will remain in the infinitive even if used with *nous* but "pouvoir" can either be conjugated with *nous* or used in the infinitive.

> Comment pouvons-nous nous attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale existe ?
>
> Comment pouvoir nous attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale existe ?
>
> Comment pouvoir s'attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale existe ?

---

You are making an interesting point in your comment. I only mentioned the most popular form and my answer was incomplete.

Both *s'attendre que* and *s'attendre à ce que* exist and are correct. "S'attendre que" is very literary and *s'attendre à ce que* is a lot more common<sup>*</sup>. Personaly I never use *s'attendre que*.

So indeed you are right you could say  :

> Je m'attends que tu fasses tes devoirs.

ou

> Je m'attends à ce que tu fasses tes devoirs.

About **ce que** :
Verbs which require "à" before a following noun add "**ce que**" when followed by a subordinate clause. [Here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=360q6soNkf8C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=%22ce+que+when+followed+by+a+subordinate+clause%22&source=bl&ots=WlZg5lw9bY&sig=WFJLkRUAtD6BJ4ZKKBfSltHquKg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ5YnC_tvMAhVEWBoKHYPXAkMQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22ce%20que%20when%20followed%20by%20a%20subordinate%20clause%22&f=false) you will find a list of such verbs.

<sup>*Le [TLF about *s'attendre que* et *s'attendre à ce que*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/attendre) : L'un et l'autre sont corrects; le 1<sup>er</sup> est prôné par les puristes, le second s'emploie plus couramment.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But why would we need "ce que"?

Comment: Also can we say "Comment nous attendons-nous a ce qu'une langue internationale existe"?

Comment: And a last thing is ce que required like in "Je m'attends a ce que vous"?

Comment: And would you say "Je m'attends a que tu fasse tes devoirs" or "Je m'attends a ce que tu fasse tes devoirs" or "Je m'attends que tu fasse tes devoirs"

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to try to add the notion of “could” by using “pouvoir” in the first clause might be:

“Comment [**peut-on s’attendre**](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/peut-on+s'attendre+%C3%A0) à ce qu'une langue internationale existe?"

However, please note that none of the translations for this construction found in the above *Reverso Context* link actually include **could**, it being translated instead as “How **do** we expect …?”

With this “missing notion of *could*” in mind, perhaps *could* could be “recaptured/re-emphasized” (hopefully without changing the meaning too much)  by using “pouvoir” in the second clause, as follows:

"Comment s'attendre à ce qu'une langue internationale (ne) **puisse** exister?"

(please note that I am including a non-negative/*expletif* «NE» in parenthesis because I don’t know if this is one of the cases where it could/should appear)

Finally, to propose a possibly less formal way to capture [“How can we expect …?”](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/comment+veut-on+que) I’ve seen (again, from *Reverso Context*) “vouloir” used loosely sometimes to mean “expect,” for example:

“Comment **veut-on** qu'une langue internationale existe?”

Or to reinstate/re-emphasize the notion of "could" in clause 2:

“Comment **veut-on** qu'une langue internationale (ne) puisse exister?”